# How to organize random values in order?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a program here that allows an user to input a number (n) and the program outputs 'n' random numbers. I need to create a loop that organizes these random values from lowest to largest, but I am unsure how to go about doing that, any ideas? Thanks,

```
// takes inputted value to "randomize" numbers too
int amtOfNumbers = Integer.parseInt(amtOfNumbersField.getText()); 
int[] random = new int[amtOfNumbers-1]; // 1 prevents array from including 0
Random r = new Random(); //for random values

// Insert random numbers into the array
for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
    random[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
}

// Output random numbers
for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
    itsATextArea.append(random[i] + "\n");
}
```

I stored the information (random n values) in the array so I can call them out later.

Comment: You have many choices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm. Or use built-in java sorting functions.

Comment: I think that java has this `Arrays.Sort()` thing.  I think that method might be useful if you need to organize arrays

Comment: Do you mean like `Arrays.sort(random);` ?

Comment: If you generate all the entries and then sort, then many choices are available.  If you want to keep the entries sorted as they are introduced one by one, the [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is a natural choice & easy to program.

Comment: Do you want to allow repeats in your sequence? This would help you make a decision on which data structure to choose. If yes, then you can't use a Set. If not, then using Set would be the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

Use a data structure like `TreeSet` to keep your data in sorted order automatically.

```
int amtOfNumbers = Integer.parseInt("10");

TreeSet<Integer> randomSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
Random r = new Random(); //for random values

// Insert random numbers into the set
for (int i = 0; i < amtOfNumbers; i++) {
    randomSet.add(r.nextInt(100) + 1);
}

// Output in Ascending order
for (Integer i: randomSet) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

To output the numbers in descending order

```
// Descending order
for (Integer i: randomSet.descendingSet()) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: This will work if duplicates are not allowed. Otherwise a TreeMap could be used with the number as key a count of instances of the number as value.

Comment: @BevynQ You do have a point but in the context of random numbers one usually doesn't want the generated output to repeat. (It's subjective to the need though.)

Answer (score 2):

Java has built-in sort capability:

```
// Insert random numbers into the array
for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
    random[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;
}

Arrays.sort(random);

// Output random numbers
for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
    itsATextArea.append(random[i] + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Would there be a way to also make it so it descends? So highest to lowest value?

Comment: @user2383438 Have a look at my answer. It supports both the orders.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them into an arraylist and define your own Comparator to sort them. For example.

```
int amtOfNumbers = Integer.parseInt("10");

ArrayList<Integer> randomList= new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random r = new Random(); //for random values

// Insert random numbers into the set
for (int i = 0; i < amtOfNumbers; i++) {
    randomList.add(r.nextInt(100) + 1);
}

//Now sort it however way you want
Collections.sort(randomList, new MyCustomComparator());
```

All you need is to define a new comparator

```
public class MyCustomComparator implements Comparator<Integer>(){

   public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2){
      //say I want descending order
      return -1* o1.compare(o2);
   }
}
```

but you can sort it however you want. Just make sure it returns -1 if you want to consider the current value o1, less than o2,   return 0 if they are to be considered equal, or 1 if greater than based on your if statement conditions.

Comment: You are the next Alan Turing 75inchpianist!